# Why a MOSFET in accumulation mode is not conducting?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, charge

In accumulation mode, the channel is not conducting, whereas in inversion mode it is conduting. But if in both cases I have free charge carriers in the channel, why isn't there conduction in both cases?

I know that the energy band diagram **between the semiconductor and the oxide** has a barrier for, say holes, and an accumulation well for electrons, but why would this have any influence on any barrier between the semiconductor and the source/drain?

[image: MOSFET] ([source](http://users-phys.au.dk/philip/pictures/physicsfigures/physicsfigures.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take NMOS as example, it has p-type body, and n-type drain and source.

[image]

If you apply a negative voltage on the gate, holes are drawn to the semiconductor-insulator interface. A conducting surface extends from the bulk all the way to the interface. But because both source and drain are n-type, in accumulation mode, it's like a npn transistor (source and drain are insulated by two reverse biased pn junctions), electrons in source can't go to drain. That is, there is no conduction channel formed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In fact, when an accumulation region is formed under the channel, this layer of charge *can* conduct current. In the past people have built accumulation mode field-effect transistors (see here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/192780/)

In a conventional MOSFET, however, the reason why the channel is not conducting is that the accumulated in the channel is of the opposite type as that of the source and drain. For instance, in an enhancement-type N-MOSFET in cutoff mode of operation, the accumulation region would be p-type and the source and drain are n-type. Electrons would not be able to flow across the p-type body due to the barrier between seen from the source to channel. In this case, applying a positive voltage on the gate to form an inversion layer under the channel is required to lower the source-side barrier, allowing electrons to flow from source to drain.

Here is an example of the gate voltage lowering the source-side barrier for electron flow.
[image]